The newton method is invariant to affine linear transformations. Why is this an important or useful property?
In my lecture notes this property is highlighted as an important one but it doesn't mention WHY it's important.
Gradient descent in comparison doesn't have this property.
What is a typical scenario where one uses this property?

If I understand correctly, it would mean it is more robust to scaling. For example if you are using it to minimize the loss function of an ML model, the result would not depend on how you decide to scale your features, so you are free to scale them however it is convenient for you.

@Jair Taylor Finite precision floating point implementations of Newton methods are not invariant to scaling, but are affected much less than first order methods such as gradient descent. Good scaling matters for all methods, Newton included.
